Numerical approximation methods for the heat equation
Consider a heat equation $\partial_t \rho = \Delta \rho$ on a torus  (so we get rid off boundary conditions), a 2D torus if you like, but it would be better to have something that works in 3D or even in n dimensions. The literature on the numerical approximation of such equation is gargantuan, but I am looking for a reference (if it exists) where the approximation method has (ideally) 3 properties:

It is explicit;
It works on an unstructured grid (ideally on sets which have curved shapes, are non convex etc, but this may very well be unreasonable to ask);
The method can be parallelised.

I'm no numerical analyst and it might well be that what I am asking cannot exist for very trivial reasons. I'd be glad to be directed to references of methods which share 2 of the above requirements. In order to give some priority, I would say that 2. is the most important requirement I'd like to have, whereas 1. and 3. are of minor, equal, importance.

If you only care about a torus, then Fourier series methods would work the best because it turns all the matrix operations into diagonal multiplies/solves and FFTs. For the heat equations on more general domains, finite element methods are likely the best bet. If you have a good mesh generation tool already, you can likely form the finite element matrices using a tool like deal.ii and perform the linear algebra and time integration with PETSc. Deal.ii only supports specific types of unstructured meshes, but they are supported in most tools. PETSc is regularly used for massively parallel PDE problems as it is built to take advantage of MPI on large compute clusters.

As it happens, I've dealt with the same problem in the past, although for a general 3D shape embedded in 3D (not necessarily a torus). I'll describe what I did. The solution outlined here is for 3D, but I think it may be generalized to any number of dimensions with some effort. This method is explicit, works on an unstructured collection of mesh points, and can be parallelized (I know this since I've parallelized it).
The main drawbacks of this method are: 1) It requires calculation of the 3D Voronoi tessellation generated by the set of mesh points (there are libraries for this), 2) Boundaries of shapes take special handling that can be difficult to implement, and 3) The time stepping scheme is essentially Euler's first order finite differencing, so it's not high order in the time step.
This method is more-or-less based on a 3D version of the 2D discretization of the diffusion operator described here. See in particular Eq. 16a.
We start with a diffusion equation of the form
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u \;=\; \vec{\nabla}\cdot D \vec{\nabla}u\, .
\end{equation}
Here $u = u(\vec{r}, t)$, and I've assumed the more general case of a possibly-variable diffusion coefficient $D$. For your problem, $D = 1$. Suppose we have a set of mesh points, where the $i^\text{th}$ mesh point is located at $\vec{r}_i$. We build the Voronoi tessellation around this set of mesh points, and say that $\Omega_i$ is the Voronoi cell around mesh point $i$. $\Omega_i$ is a convex polyhedron with a surface consisting of a finite set of flat facets. If mesh points $i$ and $j$ are neighbors (i.e. their Voronoi cells share a facet), then we define $A_{ij}$ as the area of the shared facet and $d_{ij} = |\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_j|$ as the distance between them. We also define $V_i = |\Omega_i|$ as the volume of cell $i$.
Let $u_i = u_i(t)$ be the spatial average of $u(\vec{r},t)$ over $\Omega_i$:
\begin{equation}
u_i \;=\; \frac{1}{V_i}\int_{\Omega_i} u(\vec{r},t)\, d\vec{r}
\end{equation}
Then the time derivative of $u_i$ is:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u_i
&\;=\; \frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{V_i}\int_{\Omega_i} u(\vec{r},t)\, d\vec{r}\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{V_i}\int_{\Omega_i} \partial_t u(\vec{r},t)\, d\vec{r}\qquad\text{Allowed because this is a fixed mesh}\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{V_i}\int_{\Omega_i} \vec{\nabla}\cdot D \vec{\nabla}u\, d\vec{r}\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{V_i}\int_{\partial\Omega_i} D (\vec{\nabla}u)\cdot \hat{n}\, dA \qquad\text{By the divergence theorem}\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{V_i}\sum_{j\in i}\int_{A_{ij}} D (\vec{\nabla}u)\cdot \hat{n}\, dA
\end{align}
In the last line above, "$\sum_{j\in i}$" is shorthand for a sum over all neighbors $j$ of $i$, and $\hat{n}$ is the outward normal of the cell. We have also committed the sin of conflating the notation for the shared $ij$ facet and its area, calling both "$A_{ij}$". Hopefully you know what I mean.
We now make the fundamental approximations that define the discretization scheme. First, we take
\begin{equation}
(\vec{\nabla}u)\cdot \hat{n}
\;\approx\; \frac{u_j - u_i}{d_{ij}}\, .
\end{equation}
Then, we make the substitutions
\begin{equation}
\int_{A_{ij}} dA \rightarrow A_{ij}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
D \rightarrow D_{ij} = \frac{2D_i D_j}{D_i + D_j}\,
\end{equation}
where $D_{ij}$ is the harmonic mean of the diffusion coefficients $D_i$ and $D_j$ at positions $i$ and $j$, respectively. (For your problem, $D_{ij} = D_i = D_j = 1$.) We finally arrive at
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}u_i
\;\approx\;
\frac{1}{V_i} \sum_{j\in i} \frac{D_{ij}A_{ij}}{d_{ij}} (u_j - u_i)
\end{equation}
Armed with this approximation to the time derivative of $u_i$, we can implement a first-order time stepping scheme with a time step $\Delta t$:
\begin{equation}
u_i(t+\Delta t) \;=\;
u_i(t) + \frac{\Delta t}{V_i} \sum_{j\in i} \frac{D_{ij}A_{ij}}{d_{ij}} \bigl[u_j(t) - u_i(t)\bigr]
\end{equation}
Remarks:

The quantities $V_i$, $A_{ij}$, and $d_{ij}$ (as well as the neighbor relationships between the various mesh points) should all be provided during the calculation of the Voronoi tessellation, which need be done only once at the beginning. Again, there are libraries for this.

If by "torus" you mean an $n$-dimensional box with periodic boundary conditions rather than a literal donut shape, then you'll need to find (or write) a library for Voronoi tessellations that can handle periodic boundary conditions. I'm not aware of such a library, but I've never needed to look for one.

For a bounded 3D shape embedded in 3D space (e.g. a box, a sphere, a donut, etc.), special care must be taken with boundary mesh points to truncate their Voronoi cells to properly represent the boundary. For the periodic box case, this is not a concern.

Parallelization of this scheme is relatively straightforward (unless you have a particularly nasty and uneven distribution of mesh points) since neighbor relationships are short-ranged.



Thank you very much! As soon as I have some time I will read more carefully your paper. I have one question (which may be addressed in the paper or be a very well known fact), that is: how much time do you ned to construct the Voronoi tassellation? How computationally heavy is the construction?

It's someone else's paper, not mine. As to the construction of the Voronoi tessellation, I've been using the Voro++ library, and I have found that the amount of time needed to build a tessellation on $N$ points in 3D scales roughly as $O(N)$. For around $100,000$ points, I'm going to say it takes a few seconds to build. So that's not too computationally heavy. There are other Voronoi libraries that may or may not be faster and better, I don't know.

I think this is equivalent to some sort of first-order finite volume method with control volumes given by the Voronoi cells.

@JohnBarber sorry, I thought I read it was yours, my fault
